# Open Form After It's Been Pushed

Tags: typescript

After I push a new form, how would I then open that form if it is a collapsed accordion list?

```
  /** Collapse and expand fields. */
  toggleSection(index) {
      this.fields[index].open = !this.fields[index].open;
  }

  /** Adds the first new field in the form. */
  firstAddField() {
    this.nextPage = false;
    var newForm = this.fields.push(this.form);
    // this.toggleSection(newForm);
  }
```

What is currently happening is that when I click on the "Add another field" button, the `firstAddField()` method is called, but once it finishes, it adds the new form collapsed (image below).  I am able to click on the item, then have it expand through the `toggleSection()` method, but I would like that ran after I push a new item.

[image: New Field is the new collapsed form that was added]

I am still very new to Typescript, so I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting index in your `toggleSection` function so from `firstAddField` function after add pass call `toggleSection` function with last inserted form index like below.

```
firstAddField() {
    this.nextPage = false;
    var newForm = this.fields.push(this.form);
    this.toggleSection(this.fields.length - 1);
  }
```